# Cron Expression, run every two days ignoring weekends

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Is it possible to create a Cron Expression that runs every two days and ignore weekends? What I would like to achieve is basically this expression `0 0 9 1/2 * ?` but ignoring the weekends. I validate my expressions in the following website http://www.cronmaker.com/

It must have a 48h interval.

Thanks!

Comment: What, { Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Tuesday, Thursday, etc. }, or { Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Monday, Wednesday, Friday, etc. }?

Comment: { Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Tuesday, Thursday, etc. }

Comment: I suspect you'll need five expressions - one for each workday, each to run once every two weeks.

Comment: I understand... well, thank you very much for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can safely use a single CronTrigger and all you need to do is to associate the trigger with a Quartz [Calendar](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Calendar.html) that excludes weekends. Quartz distribution comes with multiple Calendar implementations. You may want to check the [WeeklyCalendar](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/calendar/WeeklyCalendar.html) that allows you to exclude particular week days.

Providing the cron expression is: 0 0 9 1/2 * ?, your job will fire on Mon, Wed, Fri, (Sun will be ignored), Tue, Thu, (Sat will be ignored), Mon, ...

I think this should work. You can also try the [CalendarIntervalTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CalendarIntervalTrigger.html) with repeat interval unit = day, repeat interval = 2 and the same Calendar that excludes weekends.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Unfortunatelly I am using an API that only allows me to give a CronTrigger as input. I dont think I can change the associated calendar.

Comment: Very strange. What API / tool do you use? If you want, you can check our product QuartzDesk (quartzdesk.com). Paid editions support all available Quartz trigger types and allow you to add/edit/delete triggers and associate triggers with calendars. This all can be done through a web-based GUI or through a JAX-WS web-service API.

Comment: Hi Jan Moravec, sorry for the late reply. I use Jira for issue tracking and I developed a routine using an interface provided by them. Similar to [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboocloud/cron-based-scheduling-737183948.html). That's why I thought I couldn't change the calendar. Anyway, I managed to do a workaround in my routine and my problem is solved. If you provide an anwser explaining that is not possible just via the cron expression itself, I can accept it as correct =)

Answer (score 0):

I have an other answer for you. Maybe simpler.

Basically in Quartz you have three step to run a job :

- First the trigger fires because the rule of its scheduling is telling to do so
- Then Quartz check that no scheduler's trigger or job rules is violated else the executin is vetoed (and it is here we will make the magic happen ;)
- Finally Quartz run the job

If you want to use your expression (e.g.: `0 0 9 1/2 * ?`) but ignore the week-end :

- Instantiate your Quartz scheduler
- Add to it `org.quartz.TriggerListener` implementing the rule that you don't want the trigger to fire the week-end.
- Create and schedule your CRON trigger

A `org.quartz.TriggerListener` is an interface you can implements to add some rules other your triggers and jobs (see http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson07)
You must use the `TriggerListener#vetoJobExecution` method to implement your specif rules

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is actually simpler. However, as I said in the other answer. Unfortunatelly I am using an API that only allows me to give a CronTrigger as input. So, I dont think I can change the code =/